# Is there a better way to RETURN relationship._fromId AS relationship.source

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to return a JSON array of relationships in a specific format:

```
links: [
    {
        id: 3,
        source: 1,
        target: 2
    }
]
```

This is my query:

```
MATCH ()-[link]->()
RETURN {id: ID(link), source: ID(startNode(link)), target: ID(endNode(link))} AS links
```

Surely `ID(startNode(link))` isn't the most efficient way to do this?

Given that `RETURN {id: ID(link), source: link._fromId, target: link._toId} AS links` returns `null` for source & target, how could this query be improved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always include variables on the start and end nodes, and return the ids of those. I can't say which is more efficient, you'd have to PROFILE both approaches to see which has fewer db hits.

```
MATCH (start)-[link]->(end)
RETURN {id: ID(link), source: ID(start), target: ID(end)} AS links
```

EDIT

Attempting both approaches with the Movies graph shows identical execution plans and db hits, so choose whichever one works syntactically better for you.

Comment: It is cleaner! Also, I can't put my finger on it, but my gut is telling me your variables way might just be a teeny wee bit more efficient - one (two actually) less functions to call. But the bigger win is readability. So you get a tick! Whoop!